# Finding the linear mapping between homogeneous coordinates of affine camera

Tags: matrices, homogeneous-spaces, computer-vision

If I have an affine camera with a projection relationship governed by:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{bmatrix}
x & y 
\end{bmatrix}^T  = A
\begin{bmatrix}
X & Y & Z
\end{bmatrix}^T + b 
\end{equation} 
where A is a 2x3 matrix and b is a 2x1 vector. How can I form a matrix representing the linear mapping between the world point $(X,Y,Z)$ and image point $(x,y)$ if they are represented by homogeneous vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V = [X,Y,Z]^T$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 3}$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. 
Then:
\begin{align}
Mh=
\begin{bmatrix}A & b \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} V \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
&= \begin{bmatrix} 
     a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & b_1 \\ 
     a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & b_2 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \\ Z \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}AV +b \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
= v
\end{align}
Let me know if you want me clarify anything.